# Reading and comparing the characters and strings from file

Tags: java

The code below reads from a file 'helpFile.txt' and checks for an index represented by '#'.
The variable read from the file is stored in the integer c and compared with '#' if the read character is '#' without casting the integer into character. I want to know if the comparison is valid as the compiler is not showing any error.
Also, suppose '#' is found by the program in the file and a string called 'topic' immediately follows '#' and it is read using readLine(). Will the 'String info = br.readLine()' be just 'topic' or '#'+'topic'?
Sorry for such a lengthy question. Help much appreciated.

boolean helpOn(String what){

```
    private BufferedReader br;
    private String info, topic;
    private static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
    int c;


        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("helpFile.txt"));

    try{
        do{
            //read characters until '#' is found
            c = br.read();


            if(***c=='#'***){   //check if the character is '#'
                pw.println(c);
                if((**topic=br.readLine()**).equalsIgnoreCase(what)){   //check if 'what' string is equal to 's' which is the string after '#'
                    while((info=br.readLine())!=null){  //print info until the end of info
                        if(info!=null)
                            pw.println(info);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        while(c!=-1);
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        pw.println("File error.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try{
            br.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            pw.println("Error closing file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    try{
        br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        pw.println("Error closing file.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false; //topic not found
}
```

Comment: Have you ran the code to see what will happen? Make a test file that has the cases you're concerned with and check what happens.

Comment: @Lirik
yeah i tried running it. actually it is a part of a bigger program which i truncated to make it easier to demonstrate the problem.
Actually this was a part of a demo on book and I copied and pasted the same code when my codes didn't work and they had the same problem.

Comment: @Nikhar
yeah i did, actually the problem was with file name. I don't know why i have to specify the full file name everytime i deal with files even tho i have them in the same folder as the source code file.
Also I would be grateful if you could suggest me a condition to get out of the loop i.e., i don't want to print all the texts. When a particular 'topic's' info is printed, I want to exit the loop but couldn't think of any java specific condition

Comment: @nick-s what do u mean by "full file name". is it with the path? Also, are you using any IDE.

Comment: @nick-s also u don't need to check info!=null twice

Comment: @nikhar Yeah I meant path like "E:\\Programming\\Class files\\practice\\src\\InputOutput\\file.txt"
I'm using Eclipse but have Netbeans too on my computer. Haven't tried with Netbeans though if it works without full path of the file.

Comment: @nick-s check answer for your both filename and loop problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, it is woking fine with me, i think u need to check your "helpFile.txt". i used this in it.

> adad#hello
>
> howareyou

and this is the outout i am getting.

> c: 35
>
> topic: hello
>
> info: howareyou

i printed all the three vars u used. c, topic, info.
Now since you are using readline() after reading a character, u must give your "info" from next line in "helpFile.txt"

info will contain anything after topic, as you are using readline() function, it will go to the next line. try with my example.

As soon as "#" is encountered, your var

> C will have "#" (35).

then

> topic will have anything after the "#" till the end of line, because of readline();

then

> info will have the next line after topic.

If you format your helpFile.txt properly, this will work fine

**EDIT**

> i have to specify the full file name everytime

You are using eclipse, and you are saving the file in the "SRC" folder i guess. Save them in your Project folder. just one above the SRC folder and then do this.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("helpFile.txt"));
```

it should work.

**EDIT2**
you don't need to check info for null twice

```
while((info=br.readLine())!=null){
//print info until the end of
//  if(info!=null) noT needed, u alreay did that above
pw.println("info"+info);
             }
```

If it is NULL, it will automatically come out of loop.

**EDIT3**

> i don't want to print all the texts

As you used # to mark the begining of the block, you could use anything to mark the end of it. eg

> **helpFile.txt**
>
> adad#hello
>
> howareyou
>
> $
>
> Other text here
>
> blah blah blah...
>
> ...

Now, you can modify your while as:

```
while(!(info=br.readLine()).equals("$")){
      pw.println("info"+info);
                            }
```

The loop will exit as soon as it gets "$", and it won't print anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna read the javadoc for the class you are using (BufferedReader), it can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), but i think it's ok to compare the characters with == because a char is really a numeric type. But i suggest you read more about enconding, because i think FileReader will use the default plataform encoding to read your file and that may not be your file encoding. It's always good practice to inform the encoding of the file.
About the second question, acoording to javadoc (again), it will read the entire line (not from the point you read the char). Hope that helps, i'm goona try to run this later to see the results